# oozie reading and writing in hdfs as mapred user

Tags: oozie

I am running a python script in oozie workflow. The python script reads file from hdfs manipulate and write it back to hdfs in new folder. I am not getting any error while running the oozie workflow. But manipulated data is not written in hdfs. I do see that new folder by default has the user a mapred. I am not much sure whether this is related to mapred user. I am running the oozie workflow as hdfs user. The python script when ran from shell script it runs successfully and gives the expected result.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Oozie would be running your script as hdfs user.

Try logging in using hdfs and then browse HDFS to view your output folder.